# Увеличение кнопок при увеличении формы

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть пять кнопок. При расширении формы хотелось бы, чтобы кнопки расширялись вместе с формой.

Через `Anchor`, кнопки заезжают друг на друга. Как исправить?

Необходимо использовать контейнер или есть другие варианты?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вложить кнопки в [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx). Также смотрите [Руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d4d31tbk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в целом согласен, только надо протестировать что при изменении DPI экрана разметка не "поедет", ну и размер шрифта при этом не подгоняется, но шрифт это отдельный геморрой в формах. Так что думаю можно оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вложите кнопки в [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx). Также смотрите [Руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d4d31tbk(v=vs.110).aspx).